# MFA Required: Feb 1, 2022 even for SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, mfa

Consider a typical use-case... IdP with landing page to Enterprise Apps, and IdP requires MFA. Once authenticated, from landing page users can easily navigate to enterprise apps. Seamless. All nice and convenient.

Salesforce is one of our SPs.

I read this today, note the correction added on Feb 8 that requires MFA even for SSO: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352937&type=1&mode=1

> **Can we use a third-party MFA solution?**
> If your company is already
> using an MFA solution like Okta or Duo, we recommend integrating your
> Salesforce products with that system instead of enabling a Salesforce
> product's MFA functionality. Integrating with an existing solution may
> reduce your timeline and costs for implementing MFA. And it can
> minimize friction and change management needs because your users are
> already familiar with your existing system.

IdP would include information about MFA in the SAML Assertion, correct?

And in this way SF (the SP) will know MFA was used even if it was 3rd party MFA?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Right - I will revise.

Comment: At the moment, there's no enforcement of what happens at the IdP. Product Mgmt wants to eventually [implement enforcement](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/0D54S000009fnw7) by having SF look at the assertion but in our opinion that will be challenging. Classification of authentication context to imply MFA [is not standardized](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220152/service-provider-that-requires-elevation) in SAML.  Reach out to Product team and have a chat, perhaps it'll help you and them.

Comment: thanks. Understood MFA isn't standard SAML, I assumed if SF wants to actually enforce that a 3rd party IdP use MFA they would need to require some custom attributes be passed. So it actually sounds like this (require that 3rd party IdP use MFA) is a requirement that cannot be enforced. OTHERWISE, to actually enforce MFA... the only MFA SF knows about is SF based MFA. So we would potentially have to MFA twice if SF required it (once w/ IdP, and once again entering SF). Am I thinking about this right?

Comment: The IdP will include a statement of how the authentication was performed, this is required by SAML spec. Whether SF will be able to classify that as MFA is an open question. If they won't be able to do so, what will happen? Also a good and another open question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MFA requirement is a [contractual obligation](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000BtTqB). There is no technical enforcement planned at this time, although that may change in the distant future.

- OpenID: SF captures Authentication Method Reference from all OpenID Connect Auth Providers and it's available for review on Login History objects.
- SAML: SF does not currently capture AuthnContext. It is planned for the future, but due to inconsistent usage it won't be possible to infer non-compliance based on this alone.